# How to deal with unused smart phones safely

Tags: data-leakage, phone

I have several old smart mobile phones that are not going to be used anymore, most of them have run out of battery and I cant remember whether I have any sensitive data on them. How should I deal with them safely? Should I try to break them and make sure the data storage part is destoryed?

Comment: Depends on the "sensitive", if they require login or are encrypted. If you still have access why not check and reset the device? If you dont have access others might not have access either but for the residual risk physical destruction is always the safest option. "Willst du dich von etwas trennen
Dann musst du es verbrennen
Willst du es nie wieder sehen
Lass es schwimmen in Benzin“

Comment: @secfren some of the phones are too old and I don't have a matching charger at hand. And some phone screens are broken or simply won't turn on without a further repair. I don't know the data on them is safe or not if I simply throw them away. If I need to break them physically, how should I do it safely? I heard that a broken battery is dangerous.

Comment: @konchy take a look at the link from kenlukas If you are worried about the battery then disassemble the devices manually, locate the storage chip(s) and destroy them.